# Filter list with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just got started with Vue.js and here is what I'm doing: I am rendering a list of products, and each product has a `name`, a `gender` and a `size`. I'd like users to be able to filter products by gender, by using an input to type the gender.

```
var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#product_index',
      data: {
        gender: "",
        products: [{name: "jean1", gender: "women", size: "S"}, {name: "jean2", gender: "men", size: "S"}]
      },
      methods:{
        updateGender: function(event){
          this.gender = $(event.target).val()
        }
      }
    }
  )

  <div v-for="product in products" v-if="...">
    <p>{{product.name}}<p>
  </div>
  <input v-on:change="updateGender">
```

I managed to get the gender updated, but I have an issue with the filtering part. When the page loads, I don't want any filtering. In the documentation, they advise to use `v-if` but it doesn't seem compatible with this configuration.

If I use `v-if`, I could do:

```
v-if="product.gender == gender"
```

But again, this doesn't work when the page load because gender is empty. 
I couldn't find a workaround for this.

How should I approach this issue ?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use computed properties - something like this (Example bellow filter items by type)

```
const app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
     search: '',
     items: [
       {name: 'Stackoverflow', type: 'development'},
       {name: 'Game of Thrones', type: 'serie'},
       {name: 'Jon Snow', type: 'actor'}
     ]
  },

  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter(item => {
         return item.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
      })
    }
  }

})
```

Template:

```
  <div id="app">

    <div v-for="item in filteredItems" >
      <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>

    <input type="text" v-model="search">

  </div>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/dezokiwowu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This is the right way to go. Also take a look at the official docs http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-filterBy-Filter

Comment: hello, could you please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415053/making-filters-with-laravel-vue

Comment: what if we want to search this on "type" as well as "name"?

Comment: @BakhtawarGIll in that case you will need to have list of the keys you wanna filter on, and do same for each key.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `v-if="!gender || product.gender == gender"`

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm using a simple filter based on a `<select>` value. Your solution is the best in that case! Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that this is against the style guide. Eslint will show a warning if used (see [here](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-use-v-if-with-v-for.html)).

Answer (score 4):

Just modified **@Nora**'s answer.

You need to change in the template as:

```
 <div id="product_index">
    <div v-for="product in products" v-if="!gender || product.gender===gender">
      <p>{{product.name}}<p>
    </div>
    <input v-on:change="updateGender">
  </div>
```

and in JS file as:

```
var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#product_index',
      data: {
        gender: "",
        products: [{name: "jean1", gender: "women", size: "S"}, {name: "jean2", gender: "men", size: "S"}]
      },
      methods:{
        updateGender: function(event){
          this.gender = event.target.value
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

Working Demo: https://jsbin.com/qocuraquki/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 3):

```
computed: {
        filteredItems() {
          return this.allStartupData.filter(item => {
            let byName =
              item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            let byDescription =
              item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) >
              -1;
            if (byName === true) {
              return byName;
            } else if (byDescription === true) {
              return byDescription;
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

and then u can iterate through filteredItems like e.g

```
 <v-flex v-for="(obj,index) in filteredItems" :key="index" xs12 md4>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
computed: {
 filteredItems() {
  return myObject.filter((val) => { 
   return val.some((val) => val.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.searchString))
  })
}}
```

Iterate over the Object as already described above

Comment: Please add the iteration, as the order of answers will change over time.