# List.js is not working after creating dynamic element buy Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, listjs

After taking every move which i can, i am not be able to fix this issue

I have a list of item which i have to pull from api but when i append the element after getting the responce but list.js is not working it is not searching any thing from the elements.

 in `<div class="search-word" hidden></div>` this contain word with concatenated word like `name+' '+title+' '+number`

it is showing error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

**here is Html**

```
<input type="text" id="filter_search">
<div id="items">
    <ul class="list list-unstyled">
        <!-- this dynamically created -->
        <li>
            <div class="search-word" hidden></div>
        </li>
        ...
        <li>
            <div class="search-word" hidden></div>
        </li>
        <!-- /this dynamically created -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Scripts**

```
<script>
    /*========== List Js is Scrtip here ==========*/
    var options = {
        valueNames: ['search-word']
    };

    var items = new List("items", options);

    $(document).on('keypress keyup keydown', "#filter_search", function(){
        items.search($(this).val());
    });


    /*========== Vue Js is Scrtip here ==========*/
    var itemVue = new Vue({
        el: "#items",
        data: { 
            items: []
        },
        created() {
        this.postItems()
      },
        methods:{
            postItems : function() {
                thisData = this
                axios.post('http://...', {
                    _token: token,
                  })
                  .then(function (response) {
                    thisData.items = response.data
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    thisData.error = error
                  })
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Please help...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really know why you are pulling external library when this thing could be very easily done with VueJS only.

Comment: @BelminBedak thank for your reply could tell how it can be done with vue js

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791482/filter-list-with-vue-js/41791604#41791604 - are you looking for something like this ?

Comment: yes but it only search with one field what about searching in multiple element like in this solution it search only type if it has to search in name and type have a look [here](http://jsbin.com/qutusufoxe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You could use vue global nextick

```
Vue.nextTick(function () {
    let list = new List(id, options)
  })
```