# sort/filter content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

**Introduction**

I coded a portfolio website for a friend of mine as a university project.
I started to learn Vue.js and started to dive into JavaScript in general.

http://janpzimmermann.com

In some cases I'm still struggling with all the new stuff. Therefore, I'm mixing Vue.js with jQuery and JavaScript. I know this isn't best practice.
But after spending years and years with mostly html and css (and sometimes a little PHP) some things are still new to me. ;)

**The Problem**

I created a gallery grid (the content is loaded via Vue) and wanted to be able to filter the content via navigation.
Therefore, I came across the following method:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp

```
    /* content filter */
filterSelection("all");

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("content-filter");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "view" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "view" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "view");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "view");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug. 
When I open a project, don't close it with the close button and navigate to a new category and open a project there, the project which was opened before is added to the DOM again (even if it doesn't belong to the category!).

I neither couldn't find the bug, yet. Nor I was able to be sure it's not a fault of Vue.

But I tried to replace the JavaScript filter with a jQuery one (this one worked with data-attributes), sadly this wasn't working for me. As I just could add one attribute per item. But sometimes a project belongs to more than one category. (this one: https://jsfiddle.net/k5g6wcw3/21/)

```
    // Variable
var posts = $('.post');
posts.hide();


// Click function
$( ".sort" ).click(function() { 
    // Get data of category
    var customType = $( this ).data('filter'); // category
    console.log(customType);
    console.log(posts.length); // Length of articles

    posts
        .hide()
        .filter(function () {
            return $(this).data('cat') === customType;
        })
        .show();
});

// All
$( "#showAll" ).click(function() {
  $( ".post" ).show();
});
```

**Further thoughts**

I know this should be also possible to do with vue routes and maybe vuex, but couldn't find a way how to do it which was understandable to me.

thanks

Comment: Use `classList` add and `remove` method instead.

Comment: Thanks for your ultra fast reply.
Unfortunately, I don't really understand what you're writing.

Comment: Enter "classList" into a search engine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing Vue and jQuery like this is going to make things much, much, *much* more difficult than they need to be.  The  problem you ran into with your first filter was because Vue didn't know about the DOM modifications your javascript filter was doing, so overwrote them on its next update.  You're going to have exactly the same problem with the jQuery filter, if you get it working.

So don't do that.

Right now you're letting Vue draw a full list of items, then trying to crawl through the DOM after the fact adding data attributes and hiding the elements you want filtered out.  This is a lot of extra work (for both you and the browser), and will fail whenever Vue does a redraw (because it will blow away the changes you made externally.)

Instead, put the attributes in the data you're feeding to Vue, and let Vue filter it before it draws the DOM.  Which is a thing that is [pretty simple to do in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791482/filter-list-with-vue-js).

(You had mentioned the need for multiple categories per project; here's a quick example of a computed property for that:

```
data: {
    currentFilter: 'photo',  // set this from a route param, or a v-model, or whatever
    projects: [
        {name: "Project one", categories: ['photo', 'book']},
        {name: "Project two", categories: ['website']},
        {name: "Project 3", categories: ['photo']}
        // ...
    ]
},
computed: {
   filteredProjects() {
      return this.projects.filter(project => {
          return project.categories.indexOf(this.currentFilter) > -1
      })
   }
}
```

Have your template `v-for` over `filteredProjects` instead of `projects`, and you're done. Whenever `data.currentFilter` changes, the list will redraw, filtered by the new value, automatically.)

It's *possible* to use jQuery from within Vue, but it requires a pretty good understanding of what the framework is doing so you don't wind up creating conflicts between it and your external code.  (And I've yet to find a case where it wasn't simpler to just rewrite the jQuery thing as a Vue component anyway.)  The same is true of other modern frameworks like React or Angular; these all work on a very different model than the DOM-first strategy jQuery tends to fall back on.  Especially when learning, you'll have a much easier time of it if you stick to just one framework at a time instead of trying to mix things together.

Comment: sadly I can't give you an upvote, but I really appreciate your answer.
It's clear and detailed with example code, etc.

Thanks a lot. I'll try to implant the things you suggested!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words — glad I could help!

Comment: One more question. How do I set the currentFilter to show all, like on the start page?

Comment: There are a bunch of different ways you could do that; one might be to have the computed property just return the original array if currentFilter is set to an empty string, or return the filtered array otherwise.