# How to use filters in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to use filter "capitalize" in vue js 2, but when I add filters according to documentation, it gave me error.

my code

```
        <template>
        <div class="test">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="item in items | capitalize" :key="item.first">{{item.first}},{{item.last}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </template>


        <script>
        export default {
        name: 'test',
        vinput: '',
        data () {
            return {
            title: 'Hello,
            items: [
                {
                first: 'John0',
                last: 'Doe'
                },
                {
                first: 'Pavel',
                last: 'Doe'
                },
                {
                first: 'Shox',
                last: 'Doe'
                }
            ]
            }
        },
        filters: {
            capitalize: function (value) {
            if (!value) return ''
            value = value.toString()
            return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
            }
        }
        }
        </script>
```

error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/detlN.png)

Any ideas, how to corrext that error?

Comment: Need to show more code

Comment: is it ok , now?

Comment: You can't capitalize object, at least not with the filter function you wrote.In fact it accept string being passed.Your filter shall be used here `{{item.first | capitalize}},{{item.last | capitalize}}`

Comment: can you help to change this code, because I'm beginer it is a bit difficult for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter list with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791482/filter-list-with-vue-js)

Answer (score 1):

Use filters in the template syntax.

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.first">{{item.first | capitalize}},{{item.last | capitalize}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> First, we have to define in main.js as shown below.

```
Vue.filter('UpperCase', function(val) {
  return val.toUpperCase()
})
```

> Then, we have to use where we need as shown below.

```
<div>{{ name | UpperCase }}</div>
```

> Whatever function you want, just write function and call it.