# How to filter data using boolean(True or False) in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm creating a button to filter those data(games) that a user bought or have though in my code it only filters data with no boolean attribute set upon them.

Edited: added some more details on the code with firebase data to ref

```html
    <!-- This is the button I'm having trouble with -->
    <v-tooltip right>
      <v-btn small flat color="grey" @click="toggleHave(true)" slot="activator">
        <v-icon left small>title</v-icon>
         <span class="caption text-lowercase">by All titles bought</span>
      </v-btn>
         <span>Sort by Game's Title that I have</span>
    </v-tooltip>
</v-flex>

<!-- filterGames is for the search method -->
<v-layout row wrap>
  <v-card v-for="game in filterGames" :key="game.id" class="ma-2" width="240px">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'view-game', params: { game_id: game.game_id }}">
      <v-img :src="game.cover" :alt="game.name" />
     </router-link>

   <v-card-title>
     <div>
      <span class="subheading">{{ game.title }}</span><br>
      <span class="caption grey--text">{{ game.platform }}</span><br>
     </div>
   </v-card-title>
 </v-card>
</v-layout>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      games: [], //this is connected to firebase
      search: '',
    }
  },
  toggleHave(bought) {
      console.log(bought)
      this.games = this.games.filter(game => {
        return game.have === bought.have
      })
    },
  computed: {
    filterGames() {
      return this.games.filter((game) => {
        return game.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```
// with true
game_id: "006"
title: "Far Cry 4"
have: true // this is the boolean

// with false
game_id: "051"
title: "Assassin's Creed Unity"
have: false // this is the boolean
```

Comment: sorry new to vue and haven't much read those documents.

Comment: What is your question? Can you [edit] your question to clearify your expectations? On [ask] you find more information about well-asked questions.

Comment: Thank you for noting it, I forgot to ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `toggleHave(true)`, but in your `toggleHave` function you use argument as it was an object:

```
game.have === bought.have
```

That means you compare game.have with `undefined`, which explains current behaviour.

Replace `bought.have` with `bought` and it should work.

Comment: You're right. The .have was a test and it works only with those data that doesn't have a boolean property on them.

Comment: Though by just putting only bought, it completely goes blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more of a JavaScript question then a vue question. The `filter` function returns an array of the elements that meet your condition see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
If you would like to receive Boolean on filtering try using the `includes` method like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: I tried those methods but it doesn't work, I'd like to filter those data with a boolean on them. Or is there any method?

Comment: If True, it will only show those data with true on them. If False, all those data with false on them will hide after the button was clicked.

Comment: I need to see your binding and how it is setup, please show more code

Answer (score 0):

see this [Filter list with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791482/filter-list-with-vue-js)
just change

```
return this.games.filter(game => {
        return game.have == bought
      })
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that's for searching filters, not filtering with boolean