# how to search nested level JSON array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an API that has a structure in JSON format, and I need to search deeper into the third level of the array. I was using away but it doesn't work, so I was going to search for a library to do what I need someone tell me to go to the Loadash library, He said it will achieve what I am looking for. I implemented with on my way but is not working, so I need to know what is wrong with my code.

#### Edit

I updated my question and add HTML code to show you what I need it because your answers are not given me what I expect.

```
<temlate>
  <div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
         <input type="email"
                class="form-control-in"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="search"
                v-model="search">
     </div>

    <div class="page-output" v-for="(asset, i) in doFilter" :key="i">
         <target-body :asset="asset"
                :search_by="search_by"></target-body>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
domainAssets = 
[
   {
      "id":122,
      "name":"Game",
      "web_technologies":[
         {
            "name":"RequireJS",
            "categories":[
               "JavaScript Frameworks"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":123,
      "name":"Game2",
      "web_technologies":[
         {
            "name":"Composer",
            "categories":[
               "PHP Frameworks"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am using vuejs to search:

```
//...
data(){
   return {
      search_by: 'web_technologies',
      search: 'PHP',
   }
},

computed: {
  ...mapState({
      domainAssets: state => state.Domain.domainAssets
  }),
  
  doFilter(){
    let self = this;
    return this.domainAssets.filter(function(domain){
      if(self.search_by == "web_technologies"){
         return _.includes(_.get(domain.web_technologies, self.search_by), self.search.toLowerCase());
      }
    }
  }
//..
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with standard array methods.  Find the object where one of the web_technologies objects' categories contains the target string...

```js
let searchBy = 'web_technologies'

function findDataWithCategory(category, data) {
  return data.find(datum => {
    return datum[searchBy].some(wt => {
      let searchableCategories = wt.categories.map(c => c.toLowerCase())
      return searchableCategories.some(cat => cat.includes(category.toLowerCase()))
    })
  })
}

const data = [{
    "id": 122,
    "name": "Game",
    "web_technologies": [{
      "name": "RequireJS",
      "categories": [
        "JavaScript Frameworks"
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Game2",
    "web_technologies": [{
      "name": "Composer",
      "categories": [
        "PHP Frameworks"
      ]
    }]
  }
]

console.log(findDataWithCategory('pHp', data))
```

**EDIT** improved to allow case insensitive search. A probably better way to do this (left to the reader) is to add a searchableCategories property to the data ahead of time, just once, when it's received.  Edited again to check for substrings and to have a variable 'searchBy' key.

Comment: Hi, @danh thank you to your feedback, I follow your instruction but it does not take me to my goal, I feel your answer is close to my solution.

Comment: @Omda - Did you press the "Run code snippet" button? It produces results that match my understanding of your question.

Comment: @danh- yah it is working fine, but it doesn't working when I put it with my code and using a computed property !

Comment: @Omda - I'm just a dabbler in Vue, but this answer seems to have a simpler setup than yours. Can you change to this simple setup and see what happens?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791604/294949

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash but your parameters aren't right. First for [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) you should just give the root element and then the path to the child. Next because you are looking for a part of an item I'd use `join` to turn the list into a string. Finally add an `||` so that you can check for normal case, you were searching for `'PHP'.toLowerCase()` which even in a string wouldn't work

```
return domainAssets.filter(function(domain){
  if((self.search_by == "web_technologies"){
     return _.includes(_.get(domain, 'web_technologies[0].categories').join(), search.toLowerCase()) || _.includes(_.get(domain, 'web_technologies[0].categories').join(), search);
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you @deppem to contribute to my question, also I follow you the solution too but nothing happens when input field change, so how can I make it as computed property and then use it on my component?