# How can I add button to filter some data?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, filter, vue-component

I'm using Vue.js 3.0 version, and here is my code

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      movies: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "They All Lie",
          releaseYear: 1989,
          director: {
            id: 18,
            firstName: "Darci",
            lastName: "Overill",
            nationality: "China",
            birthdate: "07/13/1973",
          },
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Star Wars",
          releaseYear: 1997,
          director: {
            id: 18,
            title:'john',
            firstName: "Darci",
            lastName: "Overill",
            nationality: "China",
            birthdate: "07/13/1973",
          },
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Mamma mia",
          releaseYear: 2005,
          director: {
            id: 19,
            title:'vesko',
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith",
            nationality: "USA",
            birthdate: "07/13/1980",
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredMovies() {
      return this.movies.filter((el) => el.director.title === 'vesko' );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><h1 class="mt-3">List of all Movies</h1></div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Movie ID</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Release Year</th>
          <th>Director ID</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="movie in filteredMovies" :key="movie.id">
          <td>{{ movie.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.releaseYear }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.director.id }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

So I want to add some buttons when I click I want to filter my data. For example checkbox or button with the name John when I clicked I want to show just data with director title John or input field when someone put value John I want just data with title value, John. I m new to Vue.js so I need some help

Comment: I would use vuex and attach a function to your checkboxes to re-query vuex and apply your filters.

Comment: @JeffB Can you put some code here, to explain to me exactly how to do that?

Comment: Have you used vuex before? The best resource is to first learn how to add that (it is very straight forward, look here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/). After you add vuex I can help you write the function you need to access the data.

Comment: I didn't use it before. Actually, I want to filter some data from API requests, but I want to practice here on this dummy data. So you suggest me to learn Vuex?

Comment: There are times  when you would and would not use vuex to store data. If you want this data to persist across multiple pages, vuex is the way to go.

Either way, learn vuex!

If this data is not persistent, then you could just apply the filters to the data as you have it listed up there. This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791604/2096053

Answer (score 3):

If you're not using Vuex, I would probably use `v-model` to enable/disable certain keywords you want to filter by and then update your `filteredMovies` computed function to return the selected movies.

[Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuPGRpdj5cbiAgIDxmb3JtPlxuICAgICAgPGlucHV0IHR5cGU9XCJjaGVja2JveFwiIG5hbWU9XCJkcmFtYVwiIHYtbW9kZWw9XCJmaWx0ZXJzLmRyYW1hXCIvPlxuICAgICAgPGxhYmVsIGZvcj1cImRyYW1hXCI+RHJhbWE8L2xhYmVsPlxuICAgICAgXG4gICAgICA8aW5wdXQgdHlwZT1cImNoZWNrYm94XCIgbmFtZT1cImNvbWVkeVwiIHYtbW9kZWw9XCJmaWx0ZXJzLmNvbWVkeVwiLz5cbiAgICAgIDxsYWJlbCBmb3I9XCJjb21lZHlcIj5Db21lZHk8L2xhYmVsPlxuICAgICAgXG4gICAgICA8aW5wdXQgdHlwZT1cImNoZWNrYm94XCIgbmFtZT1cImhvcnJvclwiIHYtbW9kZWw9XCJmaWx0ZXJzLmhvcnJvclwiLz5cbiAgICAgIDxsYWJlbCBmb3I9XCJob3Jyb3JcIj5Ib3Jyb3I8L2xhYmVsPlxuICAgPC9mb3JtPlxuXG4gICA8ZGl2IHYtZm9yPVwiKG1vdmllLCBpbmRleCkgaW4gZmlsdGVyZWRNb3ZpZXNcIiA6a2V5PVwibW92aWUudGl0bGUgKyBpbmRleFwiPlxuICAgICAgPGRpdj5cbiAgICAgICAge3sgbW92aWUudGl0bGUgfX1cbiAgICAgIDwvZGl2PlxuICAgPC9kaXY+XG48L2Rpdj5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG5cbjxzY3JpcHQ+XG4gIGV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IHtcbiAgICBkYXRhOiAoKT0+KHtcbiAgICAgIGZpbHRlcnM6IHtcbiAgICAgICAgZHJhbWE6IHRydWUsXG4gICAgICAgIGNvbWVkeTogdHJ1ZSxcbiAgICAgICAgaG9ycm9yOiB0cnVlLFxuICAgICAgfSxcbiAgICAgIG1vdmllczogW1xuICAgICAgICB7IHRpdGxlOiAnTW92aWEgQScsIGdlbnJlczogWydkcmFtYScsICdjb21lZHknXX0sXG4gICAgICAgIHsgdGl0bGU6ICdNb3ZpYSBCJywgZ2VucmVzOiBbJ2hvcnJvcicsICdjb21lZHknXX0sXG4gICAgICBdXG4gICAgfSksXG4gICAgY29tcHV0ZWQ6IHtcbiAgICAgIGZpbHRlcmVkTW92aWVzKCl7XG4gICAgICAgIHJldHVybiB0aGlzLm1vdmllcy5maWx0ZXIoIG1vdmllID0+IHtcbiAgICAgICAgICAvLyBjcmVhdGUgYW4gYXJyYXkgb2YgdGhlIHNlbGVjdGVkIGdlbnJlcyBmcm9tIHRoaXMuZmlsdGVyXG4gICAgICAgICAgbGV0IHNlbGVjdGVkR2VucmVzID0gT2JqZWN0LmtleXModGhpcy5maWx0ZXJzKS5maWx0ZXIoaXRlbSA9PiB0aGlzLmZpbHRlcnNbaXRlbV0gPT09IHRydWUpXG4gICAgICAgICAgLy8gaWYgdGhpcyBtb3ZpZSBpbmNsdWRlcyBhbnkgb2YgdGhlIHNlbGVjdGVkIGdlbnJlcywgdGhlbiBrZWVwIGl0XG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHJldHVybiBtb3ZpZS5nZW5yZXMuc29tZShpdGVtID0+IHNlbGVjdGVkR2VucmVzLmluY2x1ZGVzKGl0ZW0pKVxuICAgICAgICB9KVxuICAgICAgfVxuICAgIH1cbiAgfVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+In0=)

```
<template>
<div>
   <form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="drama" v-model="filters.drama"/>
      <label for="drama">Drama</label>
      
      <input type="checkbox" name="comedy" v-model="filters.comedy"/>
      <label for="comedy">Comedy</label>
      
      <input type="checkbox" name="horror" v-model="filters.horror"/>
      <label for="horror">Horror</label>
   </form>

   <div v-for="(movie, index) in filteredMovies" :key="movie.title + index">
      <div>
        {{ movie.title }}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: ()=>({
      filters: {
        drama: true,
        comedy: true,
        horror: true,
      },
      movies: [
        { title: 'Movia A', genres: ['drama', 'comedy']},
        { title: 'Movia B', genres: ['horror', 'comedy']},
      ]
    }),
    computed: {
      filteredMovies(){
        return this.movies.filter( movie => {
          // create an array of the selected genres from this.filter
          let selectedGenres = Object.keys(this.filters).filter(item => this.filters[item] === true)
          // if this movie includes any of the selected genres, then keep it
                    return movie.genres.some(item => selectedGenres.includes(item))
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Not sure what your end goal is, but you could do the same with a text input field too.

Comment: The end goal is to show some data from getting API requests and filter that data throw some checkbox and Input field. Are you recommended to me to use Vuex for that or this example that you put? This works very well so I think this can help me very well

Comment: @Vesko_dev This answer works great for data you plan on not persisting. If this data needs to go across multiple pages, stick it in a data store like vuex.

Comment: @Vesko_dev if you're making a smaller application, then using a computed function is totally fine in my opinion. if you're wanting to share that filtered data across various components then you would definitely want to look into vuex.

Comment: Actually, I have some websites and I want to make some mobile apps with Vue+Ionic where customers can just see the list of objects and put some filters like specific city, specific price, just that things if you understand me

Comment: @Vesko_dev It sounds like you are going to be pulling down information from an API that should persist then. Absolutely use vuex. You don't want to query out over and over to an API to get data that is semi-static/static. In other words - it won't change often.

Comment: @JeffB Do you have some courses to recommend me for Vuex?

Comment: @Vesko_dev Apart from the documentation which I linked above, try this out:
https://dev.to/vuelancer/introduction-to-vuex-vue3-543e