# Display list of articles with correspondant id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter

I would like to display only articles where `id=1` in my view VueJS. Here is my code that display all articles with `v-for` :

```
<div v-for="exercise in exercises"
     v-bind:key="exercise">
     <h2>{{ exercise.name }}</h2>
</div>
```

Here is my datas :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test1",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Test2",
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test3",
    }
]
```

So, is it possible to filter the datas by `exercice[i].id` for example ?

Thank you

Comment: Use `v-if` to filter inside the template, or use computed data to filter exercises before rendering them.

Comment: Duplicate: [Filter list with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791482/filter-list-with-vue-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you filter your data in html with v-if

```
<template v-for="exercise in exercises" v-bind:key="exercise"
     <div v-if="exercise.id === 1">
        <h2>{{ exercise.name }}</h2>
     </div>
</template>
```

or you can create a computed data

```
computed: {
  filteredExercies: function () {
    return this.exercises.filter(i => i.id === 1)
  },
}
```